# XMLExists or ExistsNode: Using in WHERE clause when two XML references are used in FROM clause

Tags: xpath, plsql

I have some XML data that looks a lot like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<data>
    <context>
        <docNbr>
          1234
        </docNbr>
        <thisType>
```

What I want to do, is use a table alias that ONLY selects fields from this XML if a certain type exists (I want to use XMLExists or ExistsNode when using the WHERE clause but have not been successful). This is so that I can conditionally render data between two different XML pieces. For example, I might have data that looks like this instead:

```
<data>
    <context>
        <docNbr>
          1234
        </docNbr>
        <thatType>
```

Here are my two alias tables for this example:

```
thisType as (
 SELECT x.xml_id, c.*,
 'thisType' as type
   FROM xml x,
        XMLTABLE('//data'
          PASSING x.data
          COLUMNS
             docNbr PATH '//context/docNumber'
            WHERE XMLEXISTS('$INFO//data/context/thisType'
                 passing x.data as "INFO")
          ) c
),
thatType as (
 SELECT x.xml_id, c.*,
 'thatType' as type
   FROM xml x,
        XMLTABLE('//data'
          PASSING x.data
          COLUMNS
             docNbr PATH '//context/docNumber'
            ,specialValue PATH '//moreData/subData/specialID'
            WHERE XMLEXISTS('$INFO//data/context/thatType'
                 passing x.data as "INFO")
          ) c
)
```

The idea is to use a UNION ALL between these two tables so that one selects the other depending on which child "type" node is present.

When I try using XMLExists this way, however, I am getting a "missing right parenthesis" in my overall SQL.

Would someone be able to advise on what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the WHERE clause in the right place.

```
WITH
   thisType AS ( SELECT x.xml_id,
                        c.*,
                        'thisType' as type
                   FROM xml x,
                        XMLTABLE('//data'
                           PASSING x.data
                           COLUMNS
                              docNbr PATH '//context/docNbr'
                           ) c
                  WHERE XMLEXISTS('$INFO//data/context/thisType'
                        PASSING x.data as "INFO")
               ),
   thatType AS ( SELECT x.xml_id,
                        c.*,
                        'thatType' as type
                   FROM xml x,
                        XMLTABLE('//data'
                           PASSING x.data
                           COLUMNS
                              docNbr PATH '//context/docNbr',
                              specialValue PATH '//moreData/subData/specialID'
                           ) c
                  WHERE XMLEXISTS('$INFO//data/context/thatType'
                        PASSING x.data as "INFO")
               )
SELECT xml_id,
       type,
       docNbr,
       NULL AS specialValue
  FROM thisType
UNION ALL
SELECT xml_id,
       type,
       docNbr,
       specialValue
  FROM thatType;
```

But in my eyes it could be simpler:

```
SELECT x.xml_id,
       c.*,
       COALESCE(thisType, thatType) as type
  FROM xml x,
       XMLTABLE('//data'
          PASSING x.data
          COLUMNS
             docNbr PATH '//context/docNbr',
             thisType PATH '//context/thisType',
             thatType PATH '//context/thatType',
             specialValue PATH '//moreData/subData/specialID'
          ) c
```

Also I recommend you to name the columns and aliases better. In particular, do not use Oracle keywords.